# How to: delay subscribe popup - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm newbie about this. I'm been try to make delay on subscribe pop-up in wordpress. It's popup made with theme. I want to make delay of 30sec.

Can anyone help about this?

```js
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    
    var subscribePopup = {};
    eltdf.modules.subscribePopup = subscribePopup;
    
    subscribePopup.eltdfOnWindowLoad = eltdfOnWindowLoad;
    
    $(window).load(eltdfOnWindowLoad);
    
    /*
     All functions to be called on $(window).load() should be in this function
     */

    function eltdfOnWindowLoad() {
        eltdfSubscribePopup();
    }
                   
    function eltdfSubscribePopup() {
        var popupOpener = $('.eltdf-subscribe-popup-holder'),
            popupClose = $('.eltdf-sp-close'),
          
        if (popupOpener.length) {
            var popupPreventHolder = popupOpener.find('.eltdf-sp-prevent'),
                disabledPopup = 'no';
            
            if (popupPreventHolder.length) {
                var isLocalStorage = popupOpener.hasClass('eltdf-sp-prevent-cookies'),
                    popupPreventInput = popupPreventHolder.find('.eltdf-sp-prevent-input'),
                    preventValue = popupPreventInput.data('value');
                
                if (isLocalStorage) {
                    disabledPopup = localStorage.getItem('disabledPopup');
                    sessionStorage.removeItem('disabledPopup');
                } else {
                    disabledPopup = sessionStorage.getItem('disabledPopup');
                    localStorage.removeItem('disabledPopup');
                }
                
            ....jQuery);
```

Comment: [Java to javascript is like ham to hamster](http://javascriptisnotjava.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change it

```
$(window).load(eltdfOnWindowLoad);
```

on

```
setTimeout(function(){
    eltdfOnWindowLoad();
}, 30000);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Ramiz, 

Unfortunately, pop-up delay is same.

Comment: `.load()` event listener shortcut method is deprecated. https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: @MilanM I changed the answer

Comment: $(window).load(eltdfOnWindowLoad);
    setTimeout(function(){
        eltdfOnWindowLoad();
    }, 30000);

Comment: @MilanM you need remove this code `$(window).load(eltdfOnWindowLoad);` and add code in answer

Answer (score 0):

thanks for update! #Ramiz Kongulov

```
 $(window).load(eltdfOnWindowLoad);
    setTimeout(function(){
        eltdfOnWindowLoad();
    }, 30000);
```

I use code like this in .js, but delay is same again?